# How do I purge my system of everything related to the Unreal ecosystem?

Tags: software-uninstall

There are lots of search engine hits for how one removes this or that version of the Unreal Engine but that's not what I'm asking.  I want to purge my system of anything related to the Unreal ecosystem with, at the very least, the directory at ~/Unreal disappearing completely.

I know, of course, that I can:

```
rm -r ~/Unreal
```

But that's not really what I'm asking for unless that is the "official" way of purging one's system of the Unreal ecosystem of software (including anything having to do with "Epic" etc.).

Comment: Tricky to answer as this is not Ubuntu software, and was likely installed via a developer guide on the Epic website. I'd be looking for how it was installed - what guide was followed, and do the "reverse" of that, as in, remove whatever was downloaded and installed. I'd also look in hidden folders like `~/.config` for Unreal related things.